# Do all distributions of R.V.s have a singular part and a continuous part?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, examples-counterexamples

Consider the probability distribution of a real-valued R.V. as the equivalence class of generalized PDFs where the integral over each measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the same in each PDF.

1) Can any R.V.'s distribution be represented as the sum of a normal function and a countable number of $\delta$'s?

2) If so, does there exist an element in the equivalence class where the 'normal function' part's set of discontinuities is nowhere dense?

I am trying to work out the form of a general product distribution and it would be helpful to know what distributions look like.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist distributions which are neither discrete nor continuous.  For example, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by the Cantor function.

Comment: This distribution can be represented as a countable sum of delta distributions

Comment: How can it be so represented?  The measure I presented has the property that the measure of a singleton is zero.  So which delta functions will you use?

I can see how it can be the weak limit of a sequence of sums of delta functions.  But then, any Borel measure can be so represented.

Comment: I see! I had not properly understood.